# Meaning of пацан

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

A friend of mine wrote:

> Ты скоро будешь разговаривать по-русски, как настоящий **пацан**.

I realize this is a compliment, however I looked it up in several dictionaries and got a basic meaning of *boy, lad*.

What is a meaning of `пацан` in this context?

Comment: Фразу стоит воспринимать целиком: «как *настоящий* паца́н» (≈ a *real* lad). _Пацаны́_ — это самоназвание (autonym, the way they names themselves) людей, которых извне часто называют [«го́пниками»](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopnik). Если ваш собеседник относит себя к таковым или симпатизирует им, то это комплимент. Иначе же это, вероятно, напротив — подколка (a taunt) — возможно, вы используете что-то из [гопнического лексикона](https://lurkmore.to/%D0%93%D0%A1%D0%A0) (статья по ссылке не вполне серьезная, но как коллекция примеров того, как говорить *не* надо, сойдет).

Comment: хахаха Да это он шутил, потому что я написал "было б здорово" и этот "б" сводит его с ума :) Спасибо за ссылку. Этот словарь весьма интересен!

Comment: "было б здорово" is not that bad (not slang, just colloquial/poetic in the language in general), but yeah, somehow I use "бы". Can be your personal choice, though. At some point you are going to have your preferred style in another language. :) So it is a compliment, like "Your are cool, man!"

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov `настоящий пацан.` это не всегда `гопник`. В данном контексте это проявление уважения, что то вроде `настоящий космонавт, настоящий мужик` и т.д.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Пацаны, давайте отвечать на вопросы постами, а не огромными комментами ;)

Comment: Реальные пацаны всегда отвечают за свой базар.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there's already a great discussion in the comments :), I'd translate this as «You'll soon speak Russian like a real Russian great guy». Here «настоящий пацан» implies not only being really a man (like, for example, if you hear «настоящий мужик», that implies your manliness), but also your «being among ours». Something like «You speak English like a true American».
So yes, it's a compliment indeed.

Comment: in other words: soon you'll be talking like the rest of us.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest that a good English translation is "Homeboy" (or "Homie"). The term has a similar hint of criminality, but it can also be used as (carefully) as a term of affection.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say "Dude" is a close parallel. Пацан is literally "guy". "Настоящий пацан" is one who is to be admired and/or respected.".

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that in contemporary Russian пацан also commonly means *thug*. So, разговаривать как пацан can mean "use prison slang". Obviously, if this was in response to ""было б здорово" this meaning of пацан is quite an ovekill!

Answer (score 1):

Forget about `пацан` :) In this sentence you have a popular way of using the word "настоящий" as a connotation for making a compliment. As you are already "настоящий пацан" the word "настоящий" should be read/understood as some adjective with positive connotation like "клёвый", "крутой", "классный", "такой же как я(мы)".

The explanation about `пацан` given here generally sound.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of пацан varies depending on the context; it can denote a boy of young age (with derivatives such as пацанёнок); a slang term akin to "buddy" for a male of your age (used mainly by peers in a highly informal conversation, male to male, women NEVER address a man like this); third, пацан means "homie, thug, con etc"

Comment: Yes, it can be a boy: "[Когда был] Пацаном я здесь бегал на речку с удочкой".

Comment: I'm pretty sure, the word is derived from Yiddish "potz" (פּאָץ - male body-part). Thus the term may refer to _any_ male. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%86

Answer (score -1):

I think the best translation would be "Soon you will be talking russian like a real fellow (real gangsta maybe? :) )"
Or, maybe, to highlight slang nature of the word, one could say "real fellah" or something like that.